# What is the meaning of this question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Exercise: Consider the question of representing integers with the base $a$ . In order to name the integers in this system we need words for the digits $0$, $1, \ldots, a –1$ and for the various powers of $a$: $a$, $a^2$, $a^3, \ldots$. How many different number words are needed to name all numbers from zero to one thousand, for $a = 2$, $3$, $4$, $5,\ldots, 15$? Which base requires the fewest? (Examples: If $a = 10$, we need ten words for the digits, plus words for $10$, $100$, and $1000$, making a total of $13$. For $a = 20$, we need twenty words for the digits, plus words for $20$ and $400$, making a total of $22$. If $a = 100$, we need $100 + 1$.)

PS : I don't need solution , I just need a brief explanation on what this question is asking about as my English is not that good enough to understand it

Comment: I suppose we could try to reword the entire question, but without understanding what you don't understand this would be a shot in the dark. Please try to describe what it is about the question that is unclear or confusing.

Comment: "How many different number words are needed to name all numbers from zero to one thousand, for a = 2, 3, 4, 5, · · ·, 15? " this is the one that I don't understand , thanks for helping

Comment: OK I think I get it.  For base $10$, we need the words "zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine" and the words "ten, hundred, thousand", a total of 13 words.  Can you do it next for base $2$?

Comment: While your comment helps, it does not tell me what you do not understand. Shot in the dark: For $a = 2, 3, \dots, 15$, how many different words does it take to describe all of the numbers from zero to one thousand when written in base $a$.

Comment: Hmm... It seems bright for me now , does it mean for base 10 , the answer is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100 and ,1000? Whereas the other number like 11 is actually composed by 10 and 1 right ?

Comment: Your base 10 is correct. "Composed by 10 and 1" does not make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

It's the number of words we need to define the number system with a specific base. Since an integer with base $a$ is represented by $x_1\times1+x_2\times a+x_3\times a^2$ and so on. We need words to represent $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$... Those are the symbols from $0$,$1$,$2 \ldots,a-1$ that is a number of words and also the words for the powers of $a$ since the basic set of symbols with value below a is being multiplied by the powers of $a$. Also there is a constraint here, numbers up to only, so the limit and the question of which uses least number of words. But in case of absence of constraints, it would be infinite number of words in each case.